# Is it possible to create children nodes that provide configuration to the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The scenario where I am looking to do this is to create a generic datagrid component. I would like to use the children to define the columns of the grid, but I don't want those children to render because rendering logic is abstracted to a presentation of the grid structure (the view property below)

i.e.,

```html
<MyDataGrid data={myData} view={myTableView}>
  <MyCol fieldName='asdf' sortable />
</MyDataGrid>
```

Because the columns provide rendering information to the grid, they need to be accessible in the grid's render function without having first rendered themselves. From what I can tell this is not possible and I am currently just passing the column configuration as a prop on the grid. This strategy works fine but is certainly not the best looking strategy.

I know you can build instrinsic elements that can be used, but I think React still wants to manage them as DOM nodes. What i want is for react to ignore the DOM for the children of my component and let me just parse the children verbatim (i.e. as an array of `MyCol { fieldName: string, sortable: boolean }`).

Is this possible? scheduled on the road map? even considered?

I know it is a bit of a strange question, and I'm happy to continue with the strategy I've employed so far. But it would be nice to have the option to create these renderless "*dumb*" nodes.

Comment: In this case, I'd say try not to have rendering logic inside the children but rather have the parent (Grid component?) pass down functions as a prop to be called by the children.

Comment: that is what i am doing currently, but that means i have to pass in the configuration logic as props (which looks bad) instead of as child nodes (which looks good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with processing children for configuration is that your react component class will not have it's constructor called when you receive the children props in your parent component. This makes things complicated if you have any logic associated with the configuration node/component that needs to be applied.

The pattern I am now using is as follows (and is confirmed to be working as you would expect). I am using ES6 classes for components but the pattern is applicable to the functional `React.create*` style as well.

1. Create the props interface (this defines which props can be used in your configuration child nodes)
2. Create a dummy component class that makes use of the props you created (this component is literally just a definition and contains no code)
3. Create a configuration class with a constructor that consumes all props and performs any initialization logic.
4. Add a static `create` function to your configuration class that consumes a `ReactElement` and returns a new instance of your configuration class (the element will have the props defined in jsx/tsx
5. Use `React.Children.map` to convert the children props into a configuration instance array in your parent (this can be done in `componentWillMount` and saved to an instance variable, unless your column definitions are mutable).

Simplified Example (in Typescript)

```
interface IDataGridColumnProps {
  fieldName: string;
  header?: string;
  sortable?: boolean;
}

export class DataGridColumn extends React.Component<IDataGridColumnProps, any> {}

class Column {
  constructor(public fieldName: string, public header?: string, public sortable = false) {
    if (this.header == null) {
      this.header = this.fieldName;
    }
  }

  public static create(element: React.ReactElement<IDataGridColumnProps>) {
    return new Column(element.props.fieldName, element.props.header, element.props.sortable);
  }
}

export class DataGridView /* ... */ {
  private columns: Column[];

  componentWillMount() {
    this.columns = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (x: React.ReactElement<IDataGridColumnProps>) => {
      return Column.create(x);
    });
  }
}
```

The pattern used above is to essentially convert the component nodes into configuration instances on the parent component. The original children nodes are *thrown out* and the configuration they provide is retained in an instance array that lives within the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Take a look at [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) for an example of this style of configuration. That said, I think it works better for things that are nested (like route configs); otherwise, I'd recommend just using the more JavaScript-centric style of defining an object or array of objects to configure the grid.

In your example, `MyCol` doesn't need to be *rendered*, you just want to introspect the properties it was created with. Here's an example:

```
var MyDataGrid  = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var options = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
      return {
        type: child.type.displayName,
        sortable: !!child.props.sortable,
        fieldName: child.props.fieldName
      };
    });
    return <pre>{JSON.stringify(options, null, "  ")}</pre>
  }
});

var MyCol = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return null;
  }
});

var app = (
  <MyDataGrid>
    <MyCol fieldName='asdf' sortable />
    <MyCol fieldName='anotherColumn' />
  </MyDataGrid>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/totusu/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to look more closely at React Router, the answer was certainly within their code base. While I did try to do something similar to this already without success, it was the construction pattern that React Router uses that made the difference.